# MahApps DataGridCheckBoxColumn IsReadOnly property

Tags: datagrid, mahapps.metro

I have a `MahApps.Metro DataGrid` on my WPF `metroWindow`, which has a `List<files>` bound to it.

One of the properties of my files class is `ReadOnly`. A Boolean value, which I would like to bind to the `IsReadOnly` property of the `DataGridCheckBoxCoumn`'s check box.

I have the following XAML at the moment, but this doesn't appear to work.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding filesSource}"
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Process}"
                                ElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                                EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                                IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnly}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                             Binding="{Binding Name}"
                             IsReadOnly="True"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status"
                             Binding="{Binding Status}"
                             IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I run the application, I am able to toggle the state of checkboxes which are both `ReadOnly = false` and `ReadOnly = true`. I am expecting to only be able to toggle the checkboxes which are `ReadOnly = false`.

I am relatively new to WPF and learn everything online (self-taught), so any advice as to what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated :)

**Edit:**
If I manually set `IsReadOnly="True"` then the checkbox becomes read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem - Thanks to this [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e702047-0146-4da4-a87a-ee05c3ac05b2/how-to-make-individual-cells-in-a-datagrid-readonly?forum=wpf)

I have updated my `DataGrid` so that the `DataGrid.Columns` contains the following `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Process}" 
                        ElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                        EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseDown"/>
        </Style>
     </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Then in my XAML code behind I have the following

```
private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    if (cell != null)
    {
        file item = cell.DataContext as file;
        if (item != null && item.ReadOnly)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```